# Generating PDF/A-1b with Apache FOP 0.95 - How to embbed full fonts

Tags: embedded-fonts, apache-fop, pdfa

I am struggeling with generation PDF/A-1b compliant document using Apache FOP 0.95. Generation wiht fop goes fine without exceptions but when I validate it in Adobe Acrobat XI using preflight tool I get following error.

PDF document is not compliant with PDF/A-1b
CIDset in subset font is incomplete

I already know that I must to embedd all fonts not just subset but I can not figure out how to do it.

Here is my config file

```
<!-- Strict user configuration -->
<strict-configuration>true</strict-configuration>

<!-- Strict FO validation -->
<strict-validation>false</strict-validation>

<!-- Base URL for resolving relative URLs -->
<base>.</base>

<!-- Source resolution in dpi (dots/pixels per inch) for determining the size of pixels in SVG and bitmap images, default: 72dpi -->
<source-resolution>72</source-resolution>
<!-- Target resolution in dpi (dots/pixels per inch) for specifying the target resolution for generated bitmaps, default: 72dpi -->
<target-resolution>150</target-resolution>

<!-- Default page-height and page-width, in case
     value is specified as auto -->
<default-page-settings height="11in" width="8.26in"/>

     <!-- Information for specific renderers -->
     <!-- Uses renderer mime type for renderers -->
      <renderers>
      <renderer mime="application/pdf">
         <fonts>
            <font kerning="yes" embed-url="fonts095/arial.ttf" >
                <font-triplet name="Arial" style="normal" weight="normal"/>
            </font>
            <font kerning="yes" embed-url="fonts095/ariali.ttf" >
                <font-triplet name="Arial" style="italic" weight="normal"/>
            </font>
            <font  kerning="yes" embed-url="fonts095/arialbd.ttf" >
                <font-triplet name="Arial" style="normal" weight="bold"/>
            </font>
            <font  kerning="yes" embed-url="fonts095/arialbi.ttf" >
                <font-triplet name="Arial" style="italic" weight="bold"/>
            </font>
            <font  kerning="yes" embed-url="fonts095/cour.ttf" >
                <font-triplet name="CourierNew" style="normal" weight="normal"/>
                <font-triplet name="Courier" style="normal" weight="normal"/>
            </font>
            <font kerning="yes" embed-url="fonts095/couri.ttf" >
                <font-triplet name="CourierNew" style="italic" weight="normal"/>
                <font-triplet name="Courier" style="italic" weight="normal"/>
            </font>
            <font kerning="yes" embed-url="fonts095/courbd.ttf" >
                <font-triplet name="CourierNew" style="normal" weight="bold"/>
                <font-triplet name="Courier" style="normal" weight="bold"/>
            </font>
            <font kerning="yes" embed-url="fonts095/courbi.ttf" >
                <font-triplet name="CourierNew" style="italic" weight="bold"/>
                <font-triplet name="Courier" style="italic" weight="bold"/>
            </font>
            <font kerning="yes" embed-url="fonts095/times.ttf" >
                <font-triplet name="TimesNewRoman" style="normal" weight="normal"/>
                <font-triplet name="Times" style="normal" weight="normal"/>
            </font>
            <font kerning="yes" embed-url="fonts095/timesi.ttf" >
                <font-triplet name="TimesNewRoman" style="italic" weight="normal"/>
                <font-triplet name="Times" style="italic" weight="normal"/>
            </font>
            <font kerning="yes" embed-url="fonts095/timesbd.ttf" >
                <font-triplet name="TimesNewRoman" style="normal" weight="bold"/>
                <font-triplet name="Times" style="normal" weight="bold"/>
            </font>
            <font kerning="yes" embed-url="fonts095/timesbi.ttf" >
                <font-triplet name="TimesNewRoman" style="italic" weight="bold"/>
                <font-triplet name="Times" style="italic" weight="bold"/>
            </font>
         </fonts>

        <!-- This option lets you specify additional options on an XML handler -->
        <!--xml-handler namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <stroke-text>false</stroke-text>
        </xml-handler-->
    </renderer>
</renderers>
```

Thank you all for your advice but do not advice me to upgrade fop. It is not possible for me in near future.

Answer (score 0):

I´ve solved the issues. My solution can be find here

http://apache-fop.1065347.n5.nabble.com/Upgrading-fop-0-95-to-fop-1-1-because-of-PDF-A-1b-td41090.html#a41144